# Plotting multiple datasets on a 3D plot

Tags: r, visualization

I want to make a 3D scatter plot of multiple data selections on a single plot (i.e same axes).

I know that in 2D this is possible by using par() function like so:

> plot(6:25,rnorm(20),type="b",xlim=c(1,30),ylim=c(-2.5,2.5),col=2)
>
> par(new=T)
>
> plot(rnorm(30),type="b",axes=F,col=3)
>
> par(new=F)

(source: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Lemon-kickstart/kr_addat.html)

Can I do something like that on a 3D plot, preferably an interactive 3D plot, like the ones created using plot3D from 'rgl' package?

Comment: Welcome to the community :) As there are "r" and "data visualization" tags this question is not irrelevant but maybe stackoverflow is a better place to get a helpful answer

Comment: I found one solution to the problem here: <br/> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731187/r-plotting-multiple-groups-of-data-in-a-single-3d-plot <br/> which requires creating a data frame before doing this. I was wondering if there is a simpler, quicker way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `plot3Drgl` library.  E.g.

```
library("plot3Drgl")
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
z <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
colors <- c(rep("red",3), rep("blue",2))
plot3d(x=x,y=y,z=z,col=colors)
```

Or you can use `plotly`:

```
library("plotly")
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
y <- c(6,7,8,9,10)
z <- c(11,12,13,14,15)
colors <- c(rep("red",3), rep("blue",2))
df<-as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,z,colors))
colnames(df)<-c("eat", "pork", "chops", "colors")

p <- plot_ly(data=df, x=~eat, y=~pork, z=~chops, color =~colors, colors=c('#BF382A', '#0C4B8E')) %>% ## Like a pipe?
  add_markers() %>%
  layout(scene = list(xaxis = list(title = 'eat'),
                     yaxis = list(title = 'pork'),
                     zaxis = list(title = 'chops')))
htmlwidgets::saveWidget(as_widget(p), "index.html")
```

This saves the output as an html file.  In order to get this to [work](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/blob/master/PANDOC.md), you'll also need to install pandoc.  On CentOS/RedHat do `yum install pandoc pandoc-citeproc`.  On Mac OSX, using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), do `brew install pandoc`.